# custom code as a part of SharePoint 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio-2012, workflow-activity

I am creating a SharePoint 2013 workflow project using Visual Studio 2012. I have added a sequence where i need to update some database table. **Is it possible to write custom code as a part of workflow?** In my case, there is an "If" activity and if the condition is true, then the workflow should update the database table.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your Custom activity to write your custom code. You can follow following link to write your custom code activity.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/08/28/how-to-develop-a-workflow-code-activity-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Other approach would be write a WCF service to update the data in your service and call that service from your worklfow.