# Is it possible to modify site permissions with a workflow?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, permissions

Currently I have successfully implemented sub-site creation via a workflow in SPD for SharePoint 2013. I'm currently looking to customize the sub-site that is created by breaking inheritance for that sub-site and assigning unique permissions for it.

So far I've only been able to find information on how to break inheritance and set specific permissions for lists, list items, libraries, etc. These methods don't seem to work specifically for the entire site.

The only post I could find that was close to the feature I'm trying to implement was [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190162/can-you-add-permission-for-external-users-not-within-a-sub-site-to-access-spec).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I was luckily able to solve this because of Nintex being installed on the Farm this function is needed in.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a custom workflow activity and do the required job such as breaking the inheritance using elevated previlages.

you can refer the below link to create the activity. [reference link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114054/custom-code-as-a-part-of-sharepoint-2013-workflow)